# Compare Excel Columns A & B and return C

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am a High School Principal and I need help figuring out how to use excel to create a class tracer for my students. A tracer is a spreadsheet that tells you what classroom a student is in during a class period. A student can have up to 4 classes on an Even Day and up to 4 classes on an Odd Day.

Column A is student name (all unique), Column B is class period, Column C is room number

In Sheet1 Column A the student's name may appear up to 8 times. Column B has the class period information for example 1(Odd), 2(Odd), etc. and Column C has the room number.

In Sheet2 Column A has the student's name only once. I want to figure out how to populate columns B-I with the classroom number based on the students class period. Where Column B = 1(Even) Column C = 2(Even), Column D= 3(Even) Column E= 4(Even) Column F= 1(Odd), Column G= 2(Odd) Column H= 3(Odd) Column I = 4(Odd)

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly...

Create a new Column on Sheet1 (D2) with `= A2 & B2` then drag it all the way down. Also E2 with `=C2` and drag it all the way down

Then in Sheet2 something along the lines of:

`=VLOOKUP($A2&B$1,Sheet1!$D$2:$E$9,2,FALSE)`

[image]